# Adding babel-loader for parsing JS files keeps on failling with different reasons

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

**No Vue project**

We have an application where one of the indirect dependency has JS files. Webpack was failing while trying to parse it. So, I added a `babel-loader`

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
 
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    target: 'node',
    mode: 'production',
    module: {
        rules: [
            { 
                test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/, 
                loader: 'ts-loader',
            },
            { 
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, 
                loader: 'babel-loader',
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/vertx/),
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        path: `${__dirname}/dist`, // This is the directory that the bundle.js file will be dropped in
        library: 'stormcv-website-client', // We need our code to be bundled as a library since AWS Lambda will require() it and run our handler function.
        libraryTarget: 'umd'
    }
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"]
}
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "stormcv-website-client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "client",
  "homepage": "",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "browser": {
    "vertx": false
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "coral-super-client": "*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "clean": "rm -rf build dist node_modules package-lock.json",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.2",
    "@babel/preset-es2015": "^7.0.0-beta.53",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.0",
    "@babel/preset-stage-0": "^7.8.3",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.41",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "8.x",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4",
    "webpack": "5.0.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
  }
}
```

But build keeps on failing for different reasons like below:

```
[00:02] info Rebuilding package-lock.json
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET http://localhost:40033/@babel%2fplugin-syntax-import-attributes - No metadata for @babel/plugin-syntax-import-attributes
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@babel/plugin-syntax-import-attributes@7.22.0' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'StormWebsiteClient'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

or

```
[00:03] info Rebuilding package-lock.json
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @babel/compat-data@7.22.0.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'StormWebsiteClient'
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/p4admin/.npm/_logs/2023-05-30T18_30_22_399Z-debug.log
BUILD FAILED
```

I looked at many stack overflow similar questions
And followed below steps

```
npm cache clean --force  
rm -rf package-lock.json /node_modules    
npm install
```

But can't fix these errors. I feel like i am missing some basic thing. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved by upgrading webpack.

My current webpack config looks like this:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
 
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    target: 'node',
    mode: 'production',
    module: {
        rules: [
            // all files with a `.ts`, `.cts`, `.mts` or `.tsx` extension will be handled by `ts-loader`
            { test: /\.([cm]?ts|tsx)$/, loader: "ts-loader" }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin({resourceRegExp: /vertx/}),
    ],
    resolve: {
        // Add `.ts` and `.tsx` as a resolvable extension.
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", "jsx", ".js"],
        // Add support for TypeScripts fully qualified ESM imports.
        extensionAlias: {
            ".js": [".js", ".ts"],
            ".cjs": [".cjs", ".cts"],
            ".mjs": [".mjs", ".mts"]
        },
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        path: `${__dirname}/dist`, // This is the directory that the bundle.js file will be dropped in
        library: 'stormcv-website-client', // We need our code to be bundled as a library since AWS Lambda will require() it and run our handler function.
        libraryTarget: 'umd'
    }
}
```